# PHP to make PJAX work with refresh button?

Tags: php, ajax, pjax

**Background**: I'm building a site that uses pjax to load a container's content from html fragments when various `<a>` elements are clicked, and that functionality is working.

**Problem**: When I try to refresh a page that's had content loaded via pjax, the refreshed page only contains the HTML fragment. I understand PHP may come into play here, and I've tried replacing one of my `fragment.html` documents with a `fragment.php` file containing this code:

```
<?php $headers = getallheaders();
if($headers['X-PJAX'] == 'true'):
?><p>
This text appears when page is reached by clicking a pjax link
</p> 
<?php 
else: ?>
<h2>This text should appear when page is refreshed, and could include the full HTML so the page will render complete if it's refreshed</h2>
<?php endif ?>
```

However, this approach doesn't work (I get a server-side error). Is PHP where I should be looking to try to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In php <5.4 the getallheaders method didn't used to work unless PHP was installed as an Apache module, which may be the cause of your 500 errors.

Maybe try something like:

```
<?php if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_PJAX']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_PJAX'] == 'true'): ?>

This text appears when page is reached by clicking a pjax link

<?php else: ?>

<h2>This text should appear when page is refreshed, and could include the full HTML so the page will render complete if it's refreshed</h2>

<?php endif; ?>
```

EDIT: Alternately it looks like you forgot a ";" after the endif, which may also be the culprit for the PHP error.

Regarding the PJAX itself, generally PJAX assumes that the server is sent the HTTP_X_PJAX header, it will return only the partial/fragment content, while if the header is excluded (Ie. if the page is loaded directly, such as by a refresh) then entire content should be output.

That said, some PJAX library's (Such as PJAX-Standalone so long as smartload is enabled) offer the facility to work without any server-side changes, ie. they will automatically extract the "partial" content from a fully rendered page, if that's what is returned to them.

If this is the case, its generally much safer to err on the side of always returning the full page content. As far as I'm aware this isn't currently supported the the main jQuery PJAX library ( https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax ), although is include the standalone spin-off ( http://github.com/thybag/PJAX-Standalone ). I believe turbo links also includes this functionality ( https://github.com/rails/turbolinks )

Disclosure: I'm the author of the standalone version, so apologies for any accidental bias.